# How can I add an action to an XMLHttpRequest without using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I am doing this via the wordpress ajax hook api and I can't figure out a way.

I tried this:

```
formdata.append("action", "wp_ajax_upload_file");
```